# How to combine multiple dependent exists queries into a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries that I want to run against a certain type of product, to check whether a product exists with certain specifications.

Therefore I first want to check if a product contains a `type=A`, and if so check again if it either contains `type=B or C`.
How can I combine this both into a single query?

table cars:

```
id;product;type
0;car;A
1;car;B
2;car;C
```

Current two-step SQL:

```
SELECT 1 FROM cars where product = 'car' and type = 'A';
```

if so:

```
SELECT 1 FROM cars where product = 'car' AND (type = 'B' OR type = 'C');
```

Comment: What should your query return for example in question? And can you share your current query in full?

Comment: The query should return if type=A&B or type=A&C exists in combination. So the `SELECT 1` is what I'd expect if one of these combinations exists. No other return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to combine them with *exists*, such as

```
select *
from t
where product = 'car' and type = 'A'
and exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t2.product = t.product and t2.type in ('B', 'C')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `product` is "grouping" field in your table you might need something like this.

```sql
SELCET * FROM cars c
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cars where product = c.product and type = 'A')
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cars where product = c.product AND type IN ('B', 'C'))
AND c.product = 'car'
```